# Passport Facebook-Login is failing with 401 error in node and react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I get the following error when I try to authenticate with passport. I wonder if I am missing some middleware or something. What ever the case, this just is not working at the moment. I am getting the following error on the backend: 
 ] { message: 'You should provide access_token' }
[0] Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

App.js:29 POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/users/auth/facebook 401 (Unauthorized)

I have made sure that the access token prints on the frontend:
this is ther token blob {"access_token":"EAAGTZAFMSr8YBACcmZAaEaEMTbCKICwJqiohySMxb1pPrJaaECiPqfOqiPFln4hp2pucvSm9Pr42twDQVZBt4KZAIoEENaAINHVBcfZB8YdRM23Y9VjDSeSnUtOsyynufjCBdQyNozpI2N4bTJotZAEmLETjIqLZBxwP9VxBdDFZAYWMofEiZCUDrQwGk7fBahs8SEtzTB80kfAZDZD"}
Here is the frontend

```
facebookResponse = (response) => {
    const token= JSON.stringify({access_token: response.accessToken}, {type : 'application/json'});
    console.log('this is ther token blob', token);
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: token,
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default'
    };
    fetch('api/users/auth/facebook', options).then(r => {
        const token = r.headers.get('x-auth-token');
        if(token){
          try {
        r.json().then(user => {
            if (token) {
                this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, user, token})
            }
        });
      } catch{
        console.log('error');
      }
      }
    })
};
```

Here is the backend

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var { generateToken, sendToken } = require('./token.utils');
var passport = require('passport');
var config = require('./config');
var request = require('request');
require('../../passport')();

router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());
router.post('/auth/facebook',
 function(req, res, next){
      passport.authenticate('facebook-token', function(error, user, info){
        console.log(error);
        console.log(user);
        console.log(info);
        if (error) {
          res.status(401).send(error);
        } else if (!user) {
          res.status(401).send(info);
        } else {
          next();
        }
        res.status(401).send(info);
  })(req, res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my jwt strategy I am using facebook login:

```
require('./mongoose')();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('mongoose').model('User');
var FacebookTokenStrategy = require('passport-facebook-token');

module.exports = function () {
    passport.use(new FacebookTokenStrategy({
            clientID: '443534076456---',
            clientSecret: 'd9c12cd1c8c7fcea7abb391a0bbb---'
        },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            User.upsertFbUser(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, function(err, user) {
                return done(err, user);
            });
        }));
};
```

Here is the main server file:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
const users = require('./routes/api/users');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var corsOption = {
    origin: true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ['x-auth-token']
};
app.use(cors());


// const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;
// mongoose.connect("mongodb://user1:Voodoo12@ds263146.mlab.com:63146/fb-login-chat").then(()=> console.log('MongoDb Connected'))
// .catch(err=> console.log(err));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use('/api/users', users);

//serve static assets if in production
// if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
//   //Set a static folder
//   app.use(express.static('client/build'))
//   app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
//     res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
//   });
// }

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks your API is not able to decode the payload and extract your access token

try to add headers in yours options for the request

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: token,
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'default',
    // add headers
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
};
```

Regards,
MA